# How to inluclude picture to docx document?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-type

I use [this instructions how create word document from SharePoint list](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KH5FFC9sQ5w&feature=youtu.be).

I created this field (image) in content type

[image: field in content type]

But not have it in express blocs

[image: express blocks]

Comment: this instruction https://youtu.be/KH5FFC9sQ5w

Comment: Make sure this field is not only in Content Type on Site or Web, but in this Document Library too, sometimes it take a while when it is updated.

Comment: Yep, i have this field in document library to,but it not work

Comment: its in the correct content type?

Comment: yes. in correct content type